# Mastercard-gateway update session on android SDK not working

Tags: android, payment-gateway, mastercard

I have been trying integerating master card gateway in android app using android sdk.

While i call update session API it always return me error. I have checked on their docs but nothing found about this error.

**URL hit**

`https://mtf.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/57/merchant/{merchant id}/session/{SESSIONID}`

**Request params**

```
{
   "sourceOfFunds":{
      "provided":{
         "card":{
            "nameOnCard":"raj",
            "number":"123456789012345",
            "securityCode":"0000",
            "expiry":{
               "month":"05",
               "year":"21"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "device":{
      "browser":"Gateway-Android-SDK/1.1.4"
   }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
   "error":{
      "cause":"INVALID_REQUEST",
      "explanation":"Directly providing cardholder data is not supported. Consider using a session or token."
   },
   "result":"ERROR"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to initialize new gateway

```
        Gateway gateway = new Gateway();
        gateway.setMerchantId("your merchant id");
        gateway.setRegion(Gateway.Region.<your region>);
```

then make a new request to provide the card info, then use gateway.updateSession function as shown in the following link:
https://github.com/Mastercard-Gateway/gateway-android-sdk/wiki

Comment: and what's the callback result?

Comment: response i have post in question

Comment: you cannot send card info using the API you should use the gateway updateSession function itselt

Comment: I am getting a NoSuchMethod exception for the updateSession method. Do you have any idea about it ?